# Dynamic nested sorts using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, range

I've been to this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel) to learn about sorting with multiple sort fields. It basically says to number your keys and set them equal to the sort field.

I want to loop through an N sized integer array to sort a range by the values in the array. For example, if my sheet has 100 columns of data, I might want to sort based on columns 3,18 and 62; so N would be 3. The problem is I can't name the sort keys `"key" & i` as i loops from 1 to N.

What I have so far:

```
 With Worksheets("SalesRep").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    for i=1 to myArrayLength
       SortFields.Add Key:=Range(cells(1,colNumArray(i)).address,cells(lastRow,colNumArray(i)).address)
    next i
    .Apply
End With
```

What do you recommend?

Comment: @TimWilliams added.  I used generic names for several variables, but I think it's clear.

Basically, after looping through each value in my array, I then apply the sort field.

Comment: And what happens when you run that?

Comment: No error message, yet it doesn't sort.  I looked for ways to determine applied sort fields using the immediate window but came up empty handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Dim sht As WorkSheet

Set sht = .Worksheets("SalesRep")

With sht.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear  '<<<<< clear any previous
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    for i=1 to myArrayLength
       SortFields.Add Key:=sht.Range(sht.cells(1,colNumArray(i)), _
                                     sht.cells(lastRow,colNumArray(i)))

       'maybe cleaner as
       'SortFields.Add Key:=sht.Cells(1, colNumArray(i)).Resize(lastRow, 1)
    next i
    .Apply
End With
```

You don't need the `.Address` in your range reference, but you do need to add the worksheet qualifier, or your code will fail when any other sheet is active.

Comment: I didn't realize I had to re-reference the sheet within my referenced range.  Thank you.